# Elasticsearch limit query for script score

Tags: elasticsearch, cosine-similarity

I have an index with a few millon documents where I perform some full text queries, those queries can retrieve around 10k documents but i just need the first 100 to later apply cosine similary to recalculate the scores. I need to be able to sort the first 100 and not all the documents that match, is it possible to limit the text query so that the custom score script only has to calculate 100 records and not all the matching ones?

so far I managed to make it work by making 2 separate queries, the first one matching documents and retrieving IDs and the second one matching the 100 ids and then applying a script score function with cosine similary